# Is it possible to make custom object keys in JSON?

Tags: json, go

I have been working on a Go API and I need to encode some JSON to serve.

My structure looks like this:

```
{
  "20.0.12":{
     "someData":"yes",
     "someMoreData":"no",
     "littleMore":"ok"
  },
  "20.0.13":{
     "someData":"AH",
     "someMoreData":"blue",
     "littleMore":"red"
  }
}
```

So the child data has concrete titles. someData, someMoreData, and littleMore. These titles will never change. However, the parent does - 20.0.12, and 20.0.13

We can create JSON in Go with structs like so:

```
type TestData struct{
  SomeData     string `json:"someData"`
  SomeMoreData string `json:"someMoreData"`
  LittleMore   string `json:"littleMore"`
}
```

And then simply run a `json.NewEncoder(someVar).Encode({some instance of TestData})`

Is it possible to have these keys be dynamic? For example, if i didn't want someData to always say someData? Lets say for example the database I'm working with changed that key from someData to someDataX. Is it possible to have my json key reflect that? The code below won't run, but this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
type TestData (arg string, arg2  string){
   arg  string  `json:"`+arg+`"`
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207006/discussion-on-question-by-techy-ty-is-it-possible-to-make-custom-titles-in-json).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have runtime-dynamic types as you describe at the end of your question, but for this you don't need them; you just need a [`map`](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19). You also need to [export](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) your struct fields if you want to use them with [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal). For example:

```
type TestData struct {
    SomeData     string `json:"someData"`
    SomeMoreData string `json:"someMoreData"`
    LittleMore   string `json:"littleMore"`
}

myData := map[string]TestData{
    "20.0.12": TestData{
        SomeData:     "yes",
        SomeMoreData: "no",
        LittleMore:   "ok",
    },
    "20.0.13": TestData{
        SomeData:     "AH",
        SomeMoreData: "blue",
        LittleMore:   "red",
    },
}

json.NewEncoder(someWriter).Encode(myData)
```

See a working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/62mgpdY_v7c